# What builders does JBoss Developer Studio require on a project?

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-tools

Since starting on JBoss Developer Studio in Eclipse, I noticed that non-war projects are taking a very long time to build and 'validate'. It seemed to be related to the number of different build commands which JBoss attaches to the project.

Removing these build commands does speed the build up massively for non-war projects, but then the war projects which depend on these don't fully deploy these dependency projects any more.

Which of the below builders are actually required for JBoss Tools to function, and which can be safely removed? By 'function', I mean simply running a war project on a local JBoss. I'm not interested in anything outside of that.

```
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.jboss.tools.jst.web.kb.kbbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.jboss.tools.cdi.core.cdibuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Comment: Have no JBoss Tools installed to try out my suggestion, but I think you can try to disable validation through preferences for entire workspace or specific projects and remove kbbuilder and cdibuilder to improve performance.

Comment: I tried disabling all validation and maven integration in JBoss preferences but  that setting seems to be ignored